# which version of package do I need to not upgrade django

Tags: python, django

I was asked to fix an old installation of a Django App
I was going through the package dependencies and saw that during a server change they probably lost some python modules:

Installed is:
Python 2.7.5 and Django (1.8)
pip 8.1.2
edit: django-mptt 0.9.1

I need to install django-mptt-admin

but I get this error when doing pip install django-mptt-admin:

```
...
Collecting Django>=1.11 (from django-mptt->django-mptt-admin==0.5.8)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/ae/29c28f6afddae0e305326078f31372f03d7f2e6d6210c9963843196ce67e/Django-2.1.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    ==========================
    Unsupported Python version
    ==========================

    This version of Django requires Python 3.5, but you're trying to
    install it on Python 2.7.

    This may be because you are using a version of pip that doesn't
    understand the python_requires classifier. Make sure you
    have pip >= 9.0 and setuptools >= 24.2, then try again:
```

the question is now:
How can I find the right version of django-mptt-admin and save myself the problem of upragding all python, django and their dependencies?
Its a non documented app which probably has some more problems in it
In tried

pip install django-mptt-admin==0.2.1 (from 0.5.8 down to 0.2.1) but always with the same error.

Comment: pip is outdated... I saw that too... but upgrading that one would eventually break other dependencies? i was scared that pip (actual version is like 19) has more dependencies which again can break other things

Answer (score 1):

I think you install django-mptt as dependency for django-mptt-admin. And there in dependencies is Django>=1.11. You must fix version of django-mptt-admin and django-mptt for both.

Comment: yes... forgot to mention that one. it is installed with v=0.9.1

Comment: Try install version 0.9.0 or 0.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the release history?

https://pypi.org/project/django-mptt-admin/#history

Comment: I did, last version that states compatibility with actual packages is 0.4.1. but for a strange reason it also downloads django 2.1.7 which calls for python 3.5...